# How to Add relation to default User Class in laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-6.2

I'm new to Laravel.

I have many to many relationship with user and movie and hence created an movie_user pivot table:

I am using the Laravel 6.5.2 default authentication; in App/User.php .

The default User.php class is as follows:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
use Modules\Movie\Entities\Movie;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable, HasApiTokens;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password','profile_pic_url',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

I want to add a following relationship for movie in user class

```
public function movies()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Movie::class);
}
```

But to do this I think i need to extend Model class and not Authenticatable class;

so the problem is how can I insert the relation inside the 'class User extends Authenticatable' 
is there any method like dependency injection to achieve this solution?, and if yes in which is the best way to do this?

Comment: Authenticatable extends model, so what problem are you having since this wont work?

Comment: You can just add the function to the model without any problem. This is located in your own source, so you are not modifying any framework code.

Comment: @mrhn i don't really know whether that can achieve or not. i saw to define relation i need to extends model class so, is it fine if i define my relationship in user Authenticatable class?

Comment: @Jerodev thank you so much. now i am clear to my confusions

Comment: _But to do this I think i need to extend Model class and not Authenticatable class_. You don’t. `Authenticatable` already extends `Model`, so you can just put your relation method in the `User` model.